# How to use KHR_mesh_quantization + KHR_texture_transform to import UV with gltf 2.0

Tags: transform, gltf, quantization

I'm working on Duck
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/Duck/glTF-Quantized
I got UV (uv0) data as unsigned short like this

```
{x=3595 y=2479 }
{x=3616 y=2484 }
{x=3628 y=2479 }
...
```

In the json part, the transform is

```
"KHR_texture_transform":{
"offset":[
0.0264090002,
0.019963026
],
"scale":[
0.000233684244,
0.000234450286
]
```

So in order to get my float type UV, I tried

```
U= x * scale.x, + offset.x ;
V = y * scale.y + offset.y;
```

I also tried using the matrix mentioned here :
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_texture_transform/README.md
But nothing works, any idea why? pls help

Comment: Your formula looks good to me (assuming no rotation, which is the case here).  For example the first "X" value of `3595` becomes a "U" value of `0.86650385738` with this formula, which looks like the correct answer.  Can you see if your code is producing the same number there?

Comment: It was just a problem of precision of float number in my viewer, should use Double instead.

Comment: Feel free to post that solution as an answer to your own question, otherwise this looks "unsolved" to readers. :)